# Stripe API / CLI: List webhook attempts like what is shown in the web UI

Tags: api, stripe-payments, command-line-interface

Use case: I want to only resend webhook attempts that I know never succeeded for specific webhook endpoints (i.e. [using the webhook endpoint ID](https://stripe.com/docs/cli/events/resend#events_resend-webhook-endpoint)) without logging into the web UI. However, I have not been able to find a way to list the webhook attempts with details (like it does in the web UI) through the API or CLI tool.

So far I can [find events that have unsuccessful webhook deliveries](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/list#list_events-delivery_success), but it only lists how many webhooks were unsuccessful (`pending_webhooks` > 0), but no webhook endpoint ID or anything else more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently possible. You'd need the retrieve the IDs of the specific Event objects you want to re-send before using the CLI. The only way to do that currently is to view the webhook attempts via the Dashboard UI.

```
stripe events resend evt_xxx --live
```

Comment: any plans to add this capability?